# How can I increase the volume of a sound from unhearable (0db) to loud (60db)

Tags: c#, naudio

I try to increase the noise by doing this :

```
public void maakgeluid() {
    WaveOut waveOut = new WaveOut();

    SineWaveOscillator osc = new SineWaveOscillator(44100);

    for (short amplitude = 1; amplitude <500; amplitude+=1) {
        Console.WriteLine("amplitude:" + amplitude);
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            osc.Frequency = 500;
            osc.Amplitude = amplitude;
            try {
                waveOut.Init(osc);
            } catch (Exception ) { Console.WriteLine("error"); }

            waveOut.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose is to generate a sound, like when you go to the ear specialist and take a hearing test.  So it should start very silently, and then slowly get loader.

But I have different problems :

- i hear the sound immediately
- the sound increases to fast
- i use the loop with the i counter, to lengthen the duration of the sound, but i don't think that is the right way to do it.
- the looping to increase the sound level stops to quickly but I don't see why?

THx

based on the following code
[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee309883.asp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee309883.aspx)

Comment: Try to put a `Thread.Sleep(N)` after your `waveOut.Play()`, where `N` is the amount of milliseconds to wait.

Comment: @herman: could you please provide a valid link , link was broken.

Answer (score 2):

The bel scale is logarithmic, so you need to do maths to convert between decibels and a sample scaling factor.

In digital (floating point) audio a full signal (i.e. a waveform that reaches from +1 to -1, peak to trough) is considered to be 0dB.

As such, you'd probably want to go from -60dB to 0dB.

The conversion is as follows (assuming signed audio over unsigned, as with 8-bit audio)

```
double sampleValue = 1.0d;
//every -3db represents an approximate halving of linear signal level
double decibelValue = -3.0d; 
double linearScalingRatio = Math.Pow(10d, decibelValue/10d);
var newSampleValue = sampleValue * linearScalingRatio;
```

So now, `newSampleValue` is 0.501187233627272

Answer (score 1):

Your current code keeps recreating WaveOut devices which is not a good idea. Open the soundcard once, and then feed a single signal to it that gradually increases in volume over time. One way you could do this is to use the `SignalGenerator` class to make the sin wave, then pass that through a `FadeInSampleProvider` to gradually fade it in:

```
 var sg = new SignalGenerator(44100,1);
 sg.Frequency = 500;
 sg.Type = SignalGeneratorType.Sin;
 var fadeIn = new FadeInOutSampleProvider(sg, true);
 fadeIn.BeginFadeIn(20000); // fade in over 20 seconds
 waveOut.Init(fadein);
 waveOut.Play();
```

As spender rightly points out, 0dB is maximum, so this is going from negative infinity decibels up to 0dB over the duration of the fade-in time. If you wanted to make it start at -60dB, or for the ramp-up of the multiplier to not be linear, then you'd need to make your own custom ISampleProvider similar to FadeInOutSampleProvider and use that instead.

Comment: Mark, is the SignalGenerator class part of NAudio ? I found these version [link](http://scharfrichter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/NAudio/Wave/SampleProviders/SignalGenerator.cs) Is that the right one ?

Comment: the waveOut.init doesn't wan't to take the fadIn as a parameter, it needs a IWaveProvider, how must I solve that ?

Comment: the signalProvider is part of NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders